# poll() stops setting POLLIN after the first call

Tags: c, linux, stdin, std

I've read all the information I found regarding this matter and unfortunately none of it helps. I've written this small function as a non-blocking version of fgetc:

```
char nonblocking_fgetc(FILE *stream){
    static struct pollfd pfd;
    pfd.fd = fileno(stream);
    pfd.events=POLLIN;
    poll(&pfd, 1, 1);
    return ((pfd.revents&POLLIN)?fgetc(stream):-1);
}
```

This function should return a character if it is present in `stream`, or a -1 otherwise. It works as expected for the first call. However, any subsequent call returns -1.

The function above is cleaned up version. My version has many tests which check for polling errors. Nether POLLERR is set or a negative value is returned.

**example:**
main contains this small while loop:

```
while(1){
    c=nonblocking_fgetc(stdin);
    if (c!=-1) {fputc(c, stdout);fflush(stdout);}
}
```

running `echo "Test" | ./a.out` would yield only T and then loops without any further output.

I would appreciate it if anyone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<stdio.h>` file streams are *buffered*. See [setbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf) for more. You could use directly the [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) syscall.